# Routing Multiple USB 2.0 connections through a USB 3.0 connection

Tags: usb, bandwidth

Is there any USB 3.0 hub or device that multiple USB 2.0 devices can be connected to and still retain the maximum USB 2.0 bandwidth for each device by utilizing the higher bandwidth of USB 3.0?
These devices exist for USB2.0/1.1 interfacing (they are called Multi-TT USB hubs). 
Are there any such devices that exist for USB3.0/2.0? What I'm trying to do is connect 3 high-bandwidth USB 2.0 cameras to one USB 3.0 port.

Comment: This is a hardware question, and is off-topic here. It's more appropriate for [su]. Please review the [help] pages for details regarding the types of questions that are proper to ask here. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted this question to Super User also: http://superuser.com/questions/665888/routing-multiple-usb-2-0-connections-through-a-usb-3-0-connection

Answer (score 3):

I've been personally trying to find details about this as well. I'm trying to get multiple USB based audio cards to MUX over USB 3.0.

So far the following two URLs are giving me my details:

1. http://www.via-labs.com/en/products/vl810/index.jsp
2. http://electronicdesign.com/embedded/what-s-difference-between-usb-20-and-30-hubs

-- 1 --

This is interesting because it shows a block diagram of the VIA VL810 controller chip. Unfortunately, it sure looks like the USB2.0 functions are completely seperate from the USB 3.0 sections. This leads me to believe that, at least this chip, and HUBs that use it, can not multiplex USB2.0 transfers over USB3.0.

-- 2 --

This site spends a lot of time talking about how the HUBs are suppose to work. It takes the time to explain that the USB3.0 bus is separate from the USB2.0 bus:

> Within the hub, only the port power control logic is shared between the USB 3.0 path and the USB 2.0 path, since there is only one 5-V power path in either USB 2.0 or USB 3.0.

This leads me to assume that most if not all current USB 3.0 HUBs can't multiplex.

You comment about Multi-TT Hubs being available for USB 2.0/1.1 gives me hope that some time in the (near?) future we'll have the same ability with USB3.0/2.0.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are clearly off-topic. It encourages other off-topic questions. If you're unsure what types of questions are appropriate here, you should review the [help] pages to become more familiar with how StackOverflow functions. Thanks.

Comment: This was answered well on the more appropriate stack, Superuser- https://superuser.com/questions/477241/does-a-usb-2-0-device-connected-to-a-usb-3-0-hub-slow-down-the-hub-to-2-0-speeds